# df -h unix command output

Tags: unix, command, output

how can I get the df -h command output into excel format or csv file.

```
df -k | tr -s " " | sed 's/ /, /g' | sed '1 s/, / /g' | column -t 

df -h | column -t
```

I have tried as above but the format is not right. I'm not able to load the format into a excel or a table.

Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df -k | tr -s " " | sed 's/ /, /g' | sed '1 s/, / /g'
```

and see [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/90396-quick-script-display-df-csv.html)